# Changing page layout for an existing publishing page using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout

**Problem:**
I am using SharePoint Online environment. The current implementation is using a page layout and around 5K pages are in use in the site collection. We are re-branding out site and want to upgrade the page layouts from old to new. As all page owners are not ready yet, we like to provide an option on page to upgrade. The only solution we can go with is "Javascript".

The idea is, the new page layout has pre-configured content editor web parts with "ContentLink" configured. The updating page layout from old to new works fine, but the web parts configured in new page layout won't provisioned. But the page layout updates successfully.

I know this is limitation old days as only new pages will get the web parts provisioned from page layout. For existing pages is there any solution as we have huge number of pages to upgrade to?